# Redis distributed increment with locking

Tags: c#, redis, .net-4.5, stackexchange.redis, servicestack.redis

I have a requirement for generating an counter which will be send to some api calls. My application is running on multiple node so some how I wanted to generate unique counter.
I have tried following code

```
public static long GetTransactionCountForUser(int telcoId)
{
    long valreturn = 0;
    string key = "TelcoId:" + telcoId + ":Sequence";
    if (Muxer != null && Muxer.IsConnected && (Muxer.GetDatabase()) != null)
    {
        IDatabase db = Muxer.GetDatabase();
        var val = db.StringGet(key);
        int maxVal = 999;
        if (Convert.ToInt32(val) < maxVal)
        {
            valreturn = db.StringIncrement(key);
        }
        else
        {
            bool isdone = db.StringSet(key, valreturn);
            //db.SetAdd(key,new RedisValue) .StringIncrement(key, Convert.ToDouble(val))
        }
    }
    return valreturn;
}
```

And run tested it via Task Parallel libray. When I have boundary values what i see is that multiple time 0 entry is set

Please let me know what correction i needed to do

Update:
My final logic is as following

```
public static long GetSequenceNumberForTelcoApiCallViaLuaScript(int telcoId)
{
    long valreturn = 0;
    long maxIncrement = 9999;//todo via configuration
    if (true)//todo via configuration
    {
        IDatabase db;
        string key = "TelcoId:" + telcoId + ":SequenceNumber";
        if (Muxer != null && Muxer.IsConnected && (db = Muxer.GetDatabase()) != null)
        {
            valreturn = (long)db.ScriptEvaluate(@"
                local result = redis.call('incr', KEYS[1])
                if result > tonumber(ARGV[1]) then
                result = 1
                redis.call('set', KEYS[1], result)
                end
                return result", new RedisKey[] { key }, flags: CommandFlags.HighPriority, values: new RedisValue[] { maxIncrement });
        }
    }
    return valreturn;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a simple table with just an identity column, do an insert and use the returned SCOPE_IDENTITY() - that should return something unique all the time.

Comment: I wanted to avoid db insertion/db round trip. I have a support for Cache Via Redis which i wanted to fully untilize

Comment: @KamranShahid please do not use `string.Format` to parameterize that; I'll edit my example to show the preferred way

Comment: btw; I might be wrong, but I don't think `GetDatabase` will ever return `0`, so that check might be redundant

Comment: Have updated my answer with argument value usage. So you think there isn't any scenario when Muxer is connected but it doesn't have database?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Indeed, your code is not safe around the rollover boundary, because you are doing a "get", (latency and thinking), "set" - without checking that the conditions in your "get" still apply. If the server is busy around item 1000 it would be possible to get all sorts of crazy outputs, including things like:

```
1
2
...
999
1000 // when "get" returns 998, so you do an incr
1001 // ditto
1002 // ditto
0 // when "get" returns 999 or above, so you do a set
0 // ditto
0 // ditto
1
```

Options:

1. use the transaction and constraint APIs to make your logic concurrency-safe
2. rewrite your logic as a Lua script via `ScriptEvaluate`

Now, redis transactions (per option 1) [are hard](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Transactions.md). Personally, I'd use "2" - in addition to being simpler to code and debug, it means you only have 1 round-trip and operation, as opposed to "get, watch, get, multi, incr/set, exec/discard", and a "retry from start" loop to account for the abort scenario. I can try to write it as Lua for you if you like - it should be about 4 lines.

---

Here's the Lua implementation:

```
string key = ...
for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) // just a test loop for me; you'd only do it once etc
{
    int result = (int) db.ScriptEvaluate(@"
local result = redis.call('incr', KEYS[1])
if result > 999 then
    result = 0
    redis.call('set', KEYS[1], result)
end
return result", new RedisKey[] { key });
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Note: if you need to parameterize the max, you would use:

```
if result > tonumber(ARGV[1]) then
```

and:

```
int result = (int)db.ScriptEvaluate(...,
    new RedisKey[] { key }, new RedisValue[] { max });
```

(so `ARGV[1]` takes the value from `max`)

It is necessary to understand that `eval`/`evalsha` (which is what `ScriptEvaluate` calls) *are not competing with other server requests*, so nothing changes between the `incr` and the possible `set`. This means we don't need complex `watch` etc logic.

Here's the same (I think!) via the transaction / constraint API:

```
static int IncrementAndLoopToZero(IDatabase db, RedisKey key, int max)
{
    int result;
    bool success;
    do
    {
        RedisValue current = db.StringGet(key);
        var tran = db.CreateTransaction();
        // assert hasn't changed - note this handles "not exists" correctly
        tran.AddCondition(Condition.StringEqual(key, current));
        if(((int)current) > max)
        {
            result = 0;
            tran.StringSetAsync(key, result, flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
        }
        else
        {
            result = ((int)current) + 1;
            tran.StringIncrementAsync(key, flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
        }
        success = tran.Execute(); // if assertion fails, returns false and aborts
    } while (!success); // and if it aborts, we need to redo
    return result;
}
```

Complicated, eh? The *simple success case* here is then:

```
GET {key}    # get the current value
WATCH {key}  # assertion stating that {key} should be guarded
GET {key}    # used by the assertion to check the value
MULTI        # begin a block
INCR {key}   # increment {key}
EXEC         # execute the block *if WATCH is happy*
```

which is... quite a bit of work, and involves a pipeline stall on the multiplexer. The more complicated cases (assertion failures, watch failures, wrap-arounds) would have slightly different output, but should work.

Comment: Can you help me in transaction within stackexchange.redis ? By the way i have seen same values in output window :)

Comment: @KamranShahid added a working Lua example; let me know if it doesn't help

Comment: I am at very beginner level in redis.It's the first instance I have heard about this lua script. Let me google a bit to see how I can map my logic to this Lua scriptevaluate

Comment: I have now tried with both implementation. I have almost same time to test 10000 iteration with both logic. (Transaction
stat:05:44:18:2144
end:05:44:30:4357

start:05:44:55:1087
end:05:45:04:7907)
LuaScript (
start:05:45:39:9117
end:05:45:51:2947

start:05:46:17:0707
end:05:46:26:5237)
Not that complicated other then !success while loop retry

Comment: Now I will check if i have call from two application(different redis connection to same server)  will there be any duplicate or not

Comment: @KamranShahid the code as shown should be safe from any number of connections - that is the entire point. By duplications, I'm assuming you're talking about just the unexpected ones around the time of wrap-around. Obviously, you'll still get duplications every 1000 cycles... i.e. if you issue 1, 2, 3, ... 999, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 998, 999, 0, 1, 2 - we've seen 1 three times. I'm assuming you're ok with that ;p

Comment: I have verified the case during my unit testing.Actually it is STAN implementation for iso messaging where STAN is reset after certain number [999999]Thanks

Comment: @MarcGravell +1 for suggesting lua. I just rewrote transaction code to use lua instead. Had too many issues in worst case scenarios, like fail-over where the transactional code simply stops working properly

Comment: Thanks, very nice and simple implemenation, and even better explanation.

Comment: @MarcGravell one more question. if i have a Redis cluster then is it still safe to use this technique?

Comment: @KamranShahid yes; both Lua and multi/exec are fine on cluster *as long as* a: they only impact a single hash-slot (which must be the case if they have a single key), and b: (in the case of Lua specifically) you're using `KEYS` to pass the keys, not `ARGV` (it uses `KEYS` to do the hash-slot routing)

Comment: You can check my final logic mentioned in the question for b case

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WATCH command](http://redis.io/commands/WATCH) - this way, if the value changes, you'll get notified

Comment: Any idea how can i get it's advantage in stackexchange.redis api?

Comment: @KamranShahid try smth like https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Transactions.md

Comment: Thanks Chester. I will try it

Comment: Note: this would *not* be my recommendation; the redis transaction API is *hard to get right* - Lua would be much simpler in this case (/cc @KamranShahid)

Comment: Marc what's mean's by  the redis transaction API is hard to get right? Is it buggy or may be problem in cluster aware Redis implementation? (At the moment our implementation is not cluster base)

Comment: @KamranShahid neither of those; it is *just hard* - give me a few minutes and I'll try to write the equivalent code via the transaction / constraint API in my answer

Comment: Thanks Marc i will surely try with that one as well and analyze which is more efficient

Comment: @KamranShahid added to my answer